# Strcat, 2 char arrays of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char, strcat

I have such function, which get 2 arrays as char arguments, i need to merge this strings. Sorry for easy question.

```
    void Abc (char **a, char **b)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        a[i]="hello ";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        strcat(a[i], b[i]);       //doesn't show mistake, but it's there
        cout << b[i]<<'\n';        //ok
        cout << a[i]<<'\n';        //ok
        cout<<strlen(b[i])<<'\n';  //ok
        cout<<strlen(a[i])<<'\n';  //ok
    }
}
```

Why Strcat doesn't work here? What can i do to make this work?

Comment: [`strncat()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncat/) requires three arguments.

Comment: if i use strcat it also doesn't work

Comment: You can't modify a string literal. It's a good idea to make pointers to string literals `const char *`, and required by the standard as of C++11.

Comment: if 'a' points to something that can hold your string "hello" and the result string after strcat you effectively destroy that possibility by reassigning to "hello" in your first loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the source of your problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
    a[i]="hello ";
```

The compiler doesn't know your intent here, so every element of `a[]` is assigned a pointer to *the same string*

a[0] == a[1] == a[2] == a[3] == a[4] == ... a[199]

Even if this worked, the problem is that all elements of a now point to a char array of size 7  `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0}`. You can't `stract` onto the end of them.

You need to ensure that each element of `a[]` has a pointer to a unique storage space and that it is large enough to receive your strings. If your `a[]` elements are already pointing somewhere valid, what you need to do is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
    strcpy(a[i], "hello ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the following statement.

```
a[i]="hello ";
```

Instead of copying the string literal you assign its address.

Use instead

```
strcpy( a[i],"hello " );
```

Answer (score 0):

First, every `a[i]` is pointing to a string literal and modifying it invokes *undefined behavior*.

Second, when you're `strcat(x, y)` you should make sure that `x` has enough space to store merged `x` and `y`.

Therefore, `x` should has allocated memory and to double check, you shoud use `strncat` to avoid unintended overflow.